# SQL Trigger Looping insert to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

Currently working on trigger for update and insert for particular data row.

However, im having difficulty with this details:

**Table1** with fields

```
EmployeeNumber  |  FirstName | MiddleName |  LastName
```

**Table2** with fields:

```
EmployeeNumber  |  Value  | FieldName | DateEntry
```

What i need to do is, whenever theres a change from Table1 for declared fields, will insert to Table2.

Sample:
In Table1 EmployeeNumber 100 change the value of his **FirstName** from John to Jhon and **LastName** from Mark to Marcus.

Entry for Table2 should be looks like this:

```
EmployeeNumber  |  Value  | FieldName | DateEntry
100             |  John   | FirstName | Getdate()
100             |  Mark   | LastName  | Getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the problem :

```
CREATE TRIGGER NameTrigger
ON Table1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO Table2 (EmployeeNumber, Value, FieldName, DateEntry)
    SELECT d.EmployeeNumber, d.Firstname, N'FirstName', GETDATE()
    FROM deleted as d

    INSERT INTO Table2 (EmployeeNumber, Value, FieldName, DateEntry)
    SELECT d.EmployeeNumber, d.Lastname, N'Lastname', GETDATE()
    FROM deleted as d
```

Comment: This would probably be better written using logic to pivot the data in 1 dataset, rather than using 2 `INSERT` statements. Especially if the  dataset from `deleted` is large and having the value for both LastName and FirstName "adjacent" (the table has no ID, that we know of, but it *should* do) is important.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, have you an example ?

Comment: Sure: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62c056ea8ee8ee8f752538630d20ef78)